# Getting 404 despite having defined "resources" in config/routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, http-status-code-404, config

I have this in my config/routes.rb

```
  resources :my_objects
```

and I have app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb

```
  def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      @my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id])
      format.json {
        render :json => @my_object
      }
    end
  end
```

But I get a 404 from my JQuery when I attempt to contact this URL (via GET) using

```
http://localhost:3000/my_objects/edit/8
```

I have also tried

```
http://localhost:3000/my_objects/edit?id=8
```

got still get a 404.  What is the right URL I need to use to get data from my edit link?

Comment: Can you try running `rake routes` and paste the output here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RESTful routes created by `resources` follow this pattern:

```
method      path                   controller action
---------------------------------------------------------
GET        /my_objects             #index
POST       /my_objects             #create
GET        /my_objects/new         #new
GET        /my_objects/:id/edit    #edit
GET        /my_objects/:id         #show
PATCH|PUT  /my_objects/:id         #update
DELETE     /my_objects/:id         #destroy
```

See: [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
http://localhost:3000/my_objects/8/edit
```

not

```
http://localhost:3000/my_objects/edit/8
```

See @max answer for clarification.